# centered div web layout

Tags: css, html

I don't have much HTML/CSS experience, but I am trying to get a simple layout going where I have a centered div acting as the page container.  I have tried looking up other examples, but I can't figure out why mine doesn't work (the header appears but is left justified, I want it centered):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    background: #bbb;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0, auto;
}

#header, #footer {
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: try putting `width: 100%;` in your `body`-tag in the css file. also remove the comma on this line: `margin: 0, auto;` and make it `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: wow! that little comma made all the difference.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
margin: 0, auto;
```

should be

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma in `margin`:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

instead of

```
margin: 0, auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a , between `margin:0` and `auto;` this is an **invalid** CSS term

```
margin: 0, auto;
```

needs to be

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/k9RAh/)

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%; /* You need to mention the width here (Good way)*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    background: #bbb;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;  /* You are doing wrong here (margin: 0, auto;) */
}

#header, #footer {
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
}
```

`margin: 0 auto;` (valid) instead of `margin: 0, auto;` (invalid)